# Cant send pointer to structure after it moved to a different header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I have a program spread through 3 different C files, with the 2 header files that come with it. I originally had the header "Player.h" that I used to save the "map" structure (among others):

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
typedef struct map{
    float x;
    float y;
}map;
/// some other functions and structures///
#endif
```

I wanted to move it to its own header file, "Map.h" so its with the other map-related functions and structures.

```
#ifndef MAP_H_INCLUDED
#define MAP_H_INCLUDED
typedef struct map{
    float x;
    float y;
}map;
#endif
```

I made the Map.c file as normal, wrote a function in it that would work, but I didn"t call for the function in main.c yet.
I made the "map" data structure in main.c as followed:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Map.h"
int main(){
... /// some other stuff being done

map map;
map.x = 0;
map.y = 0;
... /// more stuff being done

callfunctioninplayer(&map, /// other variables///)
}
```

so I call the function in player.c, where I also included map.h using `#included "Map.h"`. But after trying to compile it, it gave me an error everywhere where I asked for the `map* map` structure with the errors:

```
In file included from ./main.c:10:0:
./Player.h:21:55: error: unknown type name ‘map’
 void movementPlayer(int* inputPlayer, player* player, map* map, unsigned int countFrames);

./Player.h:21:55: error: unknown type name ‘map’
 void movementPlayer(int* inputPlayer, player* player, map* map, unsigned int countFrames);
                                                       ^~~
In file included from ./Map.c:10:0:
./Player.h:21:55: error: unknown type name ‘map’
 void movementPlayer(int* inputPlayer, player* player, map* map, unsigned int countFrames);
```

I checked if map.h was defined everywhere, it is, and I tested it again after putting the map struct back in player.h. Putting it back in player.h worked, but why didn't it in map.h?
*I'm sorry if this is asked a lot, I looked through some posts but couldn't find anyone with the same error*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `map` is being used in Player.h, but Map.h hasn't been included at the point Player.h is included, and presumably you didn't include Map.h in Player.h.

If Player.h needs definitions in Map.h, then you need to `#include "Map.h"` in Player.h.

Comment: I already had done``#include "Map.h"`` in all files (main.c, player.c, map.c) when the error appeared. Putting it in ``Player.h`` did fix the issue of it not being recognised as a datatype anymore. But the error shifted over to the player structure, which was also included in every file. Adding player.h and/or map.h to both files didn't solve these errors tho, which seem to be the same but this time targeting all ``player* player`` pointers in functions

Comment: @atiedebee Then it sounds like you need to put `player` and `map` into a seperate header that's included in both Map.h and Player.h.

Comment: What do you mean by that? something like this? ```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED #define GAME_H_INCLUDED #include "Player.h" #include "Map.h" #endif
```
Sorry for the formatting, its just a normal header with "Player.h" and "Map.h" included, is that the way to do it?
and include "Game.h" in every file?

Comment: @atiedebee No, put `player` and `map` in Game.h then include that in Map.h and Player.h.

Comment: Just the structures or the words?

Comment: @atiedebee The stuctures, as they are what is needed in the other files.

Comment: Ah ok, I tried this and it worked! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Or just switch the order: `Map.h` before `Player.h`. But I agree; a high-degree of connectivity probably means that they should be in one header.